# If you add 1 to a pointer, does it really add 1, or does it add 4 or 32?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Suppose you have a pointer, produced by something like

```
int a = 5;
int* pointer = &a;
```

And suppose you add 1 to the pointer, as in

```
pointer = pointer + 1;
```

Now suppose the original bitwise representation of the pointer was

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Then is the new representation `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001`?  Or `00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000`?  Or neither of those?

I am confused because I feel like adding 1 to a number should add 1 to its bitwise representation.  But if you add 1 to the index of an array, the new address is 32 bits away from the old address.

Comment: The latter; it'll move sizeof(int) bytes in memory

Comment: Moving an `int *` by one byte isn't useful that often.

Comment: Lookup "pointer arithmetic" in [your favorite search engine](http://google.com)

Comment: Simple answer is: it adds a number of bytes equal to the size of the data type of the pointer. If that type is `int`, then it increases with 4 or 8, depending on the architecture.

Comment: "*I feel like adding 1 to a number should add 1 to its bitwise representation*" Why? Isn't it much more sensible for adding 1 to a number should add one to its value? Adding one to a value's encoding is something you would almost never want to do.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Also, pointers are not numbers. If they were, you could add two pointers.

Comment: @fredoverflow The OP's comment wasn't about pointers, it was about numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the type of pointer.

The pointer actually are all the same, as far as the actual data is concerned. An `int*` keeps the same kind of data as a `char*` (integer values representing memory locations). The reason why we care about the kind of data a pointer points to is, besides knowing how to decode it (i.e. dereference it), to know how to point to the next element of the same type. So, let `p` be a pointer to an object (object not as in oop, but as any variable that has some storage associated) of type `T`. Then, `intptr_t(p + 1) = intptr_t(p) + sizeof(T)`.

This is particularly useful in working with arrays and, if you think a little bit, it makes sense. Consider the declaration `int *p = 0x100` and assume that at address 100 is a valid integer value. What sense would it make to access the integer value from 0x101 (this is actually illegal, since ints must start on addresses divisible by 4 - considering sizeof(int) = 4)?

Comment: Thanks, that provided good intuition.

Answer (score 6):

When you add `1` to `pointer`, then compiler do the following arithmetic behind the scene

```
pointer = pointer + sizeof(int)*1
```

So, it will depend on the size of data type. On a 32-bit machine size of `int` is 4-bytes, therefore `4*1 = 4` will be added to `pointer`.

For example, if `pointer` is pointing to memory addresss `0x00000000` then it will be pointing at `0x00000004` after adding `1` to it.

[image]

Comment: Wait, so would it be 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100?

Comment: Yes. It would be `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100`.